Should I check "Required to Leave" while filing my visa application?
I came to the UK on a student visa. The validity was 2 years. Due to some issues, I had to withdraw from my course and went back my home country after 2 weeks of stay. After 2 months I got a "Decision to cancel leave" mail from UKVI which mentioned:

Next steps
You must now do one of the following before your permission ends:


• tell us any other reasons you think you should be allowed to remain in the UK
by making a new application to stay in the UK


• seek help and advice on returning home


• leave the UK

Now I am applying a UK visa again. There is a question that asks you about previous history in the UK and in it, they ask, if I have ever been deported, removed, refused or "required to leave the UK"? (There are also other options).
Should I check the "Required to leave the UK" option or not?

Just to be clear, at the time you were "Required to Leave", you had already left?

Without knowing what the other options are, IMHO unless they include ‘left voluntarily before I received notification of decision to cancel leave’, the safest action is to tick ‘required to leave’ and explain further in the application or a letter. UKVI will have the information anyway.

I concur with @Traveller, I would probably say yes, and add details explaining that when you were asked to leave, you had actually already left. Make sure you have some evidence that you left the UK on the date you give them (ideally a boarding pass, or some evidence that you were in your home country shortly after that), in case they have trouble verifying that you left on that date with the data they already have.

Turning comments into an answer:
Without knowing what the other options are, IMHO unless they include ‘left voluntarily before I received notification of decision to cancel leave’, the safest action is to tick ‘required to leave’ and explain in the application or a letter that when you were asked to leave, you had actually already left.
Make sure you have some evidence that you left the UK on the date you give them (ideally a boarding pass, or some evidence that you were in your home country shortly after that), in case UKVI has trouble verifying that you left on that date with the data it already has.

Speculative question: Is it possible/likely that the decision to cancel leave was triggered by the OP having left after having got leave to visit (perhaps it was seen as abandoning their stay, if that's a thing). If so, the whole "Next steps" section might just be boiler-plate text.

@TripeHound No. The OP had a student visa and withdrew from their studies, which will automatically trigger visa cancellation in most cases. See eg [this description of the process](https://www.gre.ac.uk/visa/during-your-studies/interrupting-or-withdrawing-from-study#:~:text=The%20following%20process%20takes%20place,UKVI%20(in%20most%20cases).
